# nginx http to https redirect configuration not working

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy

I have configured my nginx based on the documentation provided and articles available from web. It's not completely working specifically http to https.
I tried different changes but still not be able to execute successfully...Please have a look.

Few imp points : My . nodejs app is running on port 3000.
Ghost blog running on 2368.

```
HTTP — redirect all traffic to HTTPS
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name domainname.com www.domainname.com;
    return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl http2 default_server;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2 default_server;
    server_name www.domainname.com;
    error_page 497 https://www.domainname.com$request_uri;

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/domainname.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/domainname.com/privkey.pem;
    ssl_session_timeout 1d;
    ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:50m;
    ssl_session_tickets off;

    # intermediate configuration. tweak to your needs.
    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_ciphers KEY_HERE;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

    # HSTS (ngx_http_headers_module is required) (15768000 seconds = 6 months)
    add_header Strict-Transport-Security max-age=15768000;
   # OCSP Stapling ---
    # fetch OCSP records from URL in ssl_certificate and cache them
    ssl_stapling on;
    ssl_stapling_verify on;

    ## verify chain of trust of OCSP response using Root CA and Intermediate certs
    # ssl_trusted_certificate /etc/ssl/certs/dhparam.pem;

    resolver 8.8.8.8;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }

    location /blog {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:2368;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This issue is resolved.

Everything is correct with nginx configuration. Issue was with Google console platform. There is a check box in GCP config with name Allow HTTP traffic, which was unchecked by default. I made the change and it started working. Thanks for the reply.

Answer (score -1):

I recommend you to do as below:

```
location / {
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}
```

Comment: I tried this and kept other lines as well in 'location / { }` because I want to use proxy_pass etc...added this line the end before } ...It did not work...Let me know if this was the ask..Thanks

Comment: I think you want me to place this code in server block instead of location...Please confirm..

Comment: return works inside location, I think yoh have another problem, you can send some logs.